# Literaly I just inserted the View and i guess google didn't read it

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-library

I initiated a proyect with basic views activity and and simply inserted the component and looks like this,
checked the dependencies in my gradle and
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
are there

search for the dependencies and add again android xcompat

Comment: I don't even know what's the question here...

Comment: I couldn't attach the image but my view isn;t appearint , it is a androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView and all android gives me in the preview is an URL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.